# Copy-Paste range (inc. entirerow) from Min to Max

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

(1) I´d appreciate if somebody could help me briefly. I can not really figure out how to include the formula "entire row" into the code below, so that the macro copies from min to max in column F but also the entire row of each data point...

```
Sub Enter_Formula()
Dim sht As Worksheet, summarySht As Worksheet

Set summarySht = Worksheets("SummarySheet") '<--| change "Summary" to your actual "Summary" sheet name

For Each sht In Worksheets
   If sht.Name <> summarySht.Name Then
        With sht.Range("F15000:F20000")
            .Parent.Range(.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues), .EntireColumn.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Max(.EntireColumn), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)).Copy summarySht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        End With
   End If

Next

End Sub
```

(2) The other question is, how to modify the code, so that excel creates an extra "summary" sheet for each sheet the macro runs over. I do not want one summarysheet for all the found ranges because that is too confusing for the reader.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So if finds the minimum on row 15000 and the max on row 100 you want to copy the whole of rows 100 to 15000 to a new sheet?

Comment: Logically yes, but in this case the minimum will always be before the maximum @SJR

Comment: OK, suggested code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not sure you really need to copy the whole row though do you?) The summary sheet name is just the sheet name preceded by "Summary".

```
Sub x()

Dim sht As Worksheet, summarySht As Worksheet
Dim rMin As Range, rMax As Range

For Each sht In Worksheets
   If Not sht.Name Like "Summary*" Then
        Set summarySht = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        summarySht.Name = "Summary " & sht.Name
        With sht.Range("F15000:F20000")
            Set rMin = .Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set rMax = .EntireColumn.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Max(.EntireColumn))
            .Parent.Range(rMin, rMax).EntireRow.Copy summarySht.Range("A1")
        End With
   End If
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: it works exactly as I imagined, thank you very much!